# Need help creating a searchable "FAQ" list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a searchable FAQ web part in my employer's SharePoint Online. It's easy enough to create a List, then use the Group By feature to format the list in the form of a FAQ list. And, on the List page itself, the search box at the top of the page searches and filters the list:

[image]

But I need to add the List as an App on another page and, in that case, the search box at the top of that page searches the entire site, not just the list:

[image]

On the page shown in the above image, I have attempted to use the PnP Search Box and PnP Search Results web parts to filter the list but, so far, unsuccessfully. Here is the configuration of the Search Box:

[image]

And here are what I think are the relevant parts of the configuration for the Search Results web part:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But the FAQ List items are not being filtered. The configuration of the PnP Search Box and Search Results web parts are a bit complex, and I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Am I on the right track? Should the PnP Search Box and Search Results web parts work for my purposes? Or is there another option I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a DetailsList with Search function enabled.

Here is the sample,

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/compact

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you Murtuza! That looks like a handy app that would address our need, but we're looking for something a bit more "out of the box." Can the data displayed by that app be stored in a SharePoint List? That was my plan, to make it easy for the content owners of our SharePoint site to maintain.

Comment: Absolutely! The list stored data can be displayed as the faq style. 

If you need help let me know

Comment: Thanks again Murtuza! I was unable to figure out how to implement the DetailsList app in my SharePoint Online environment. I know it is possible, but implementing it may be a bit outside of my skillset. Plus, we're trying to stick with OOTB SharePoint web parts. So I kept working with the PnP Search Box, Search Results and Search Filters web parts until I got them working to my management's satisfaction. So I'm going to leave it at that.